# Visual Studio Debugging error: cv2.pdb not included

Tags: python

hi when I wrote these Codes in Pycharm 2020.1 :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('ml.png', 0)
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img, None)

# compute the descriptors with ORB
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

# draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, color=(0, 255, 0), flags=0)
```

Python has Stopped working and When Debug the program

Message : 'an unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe (6344) '

and Go into Visual Studio this Message : ' unhandled exception at 0x000007FEDEC488AA (cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd) in python.exe:0xC0000005: access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000 '

press Break and Messages: ' No symbols loaded

cv2.pdb not included

Message : ' Symbol loading for cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd was skipped because it is not specified in the included modules list'

Please Explain to me How To fix This Big Problem

Comment: hi i saw some answers about this problem and changed Visual studio Settings but it didnt solve - I want Uninstall  my Visual studio and Install Newest Version- maybe My visual studio has problem. anybody can help me? what is your Ideas?

Comment: file cv2.pdb cannot find in my folders in my computer- i searched for this file but it isnt in system. do must Install Visual studio again or Pycharm ? or download cv2.pdb file into system? Please Help me